# AttributeError: module 'dominate.tags' has no attribute 'input'

Tags: flask

I am running a flask application on python 3.9 and following flask and getting following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_bootstrap/forms.py", line 51, in _wrapped_input
    wrap.add(tags.input(type=type, _class=' '.join(classes), **kwargs))
AttributeError: module 'dominate.tags' has no attribute 'input'
```

I can see that input has been removed in dominate/tags.py but not sure which version of dominate should I use!

Comment: Flask==2.2.2
flask-appconfig==0.11.1
Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.7.1
Flask-Debug==0.4.3
Flask-Moment==1.0.5
flask-nav==0.6
Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.0.2
Flask-WTF==1.0.1
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
packaging==22.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2022.6
requests==2.28.1
six==1.16.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.45
urllib3==1.26.13
visitor==0.1.3
Werkzeug==2.2.2
WTForms==3.0.1
zipp==3.11.0

Comment: Don't know if it helps but in a script I am using the tag used is `tags.input_` not just input